# Removing an item from a linked list

Tags: python, class

I have a linked list class and I'm trying to write a class function to remove any item from the linked list.

Example, if my linked list contains:

```
1
2
3
4
5
```

and i want to remove 4, it outputs:

```
1
2
3
5
```

here's my code:

```
def remove(self,item):
    if self.isEmpty():
        raise StopIteration("List is empty")
    else:
        element = self.head
        if element.next.item == item:
            element.next = element.next.next
        self.count-=1
        return True
```

the problem with my code is that, it only considers the first item it sees in the linked list and remove it at first sight.

Example, if i remove 1, since it's the first element, it works but if i were to remove 3, the program doesn't remove the element. I'm wondering if I'm missing out on anything that causes it to not work for elements other than 1

Comment: There is no iteration in the code.

Comment: Do you have an example for the class definition? BTW, you're not defining a class function but an instance method.

Answer (score 1):

You should iterate through all the elements to find your item. You can either do through recurssion(call remove function again and again) or by looping through. This code shows how to loop through

```
def remove(self,item):
    if self.isEmpty():
        raise StopIteration("List is empty")
    else:
        element = self.head
        // if 1st element itself
        if element.item == item:
            self.head = element.next
        // other than first
        while element.next != null:
            if element.next.item == item:
                element.next = element.next.next
                self.count-=1
                return True
            element = element.next
        return False // return Flase if 'item' is not present in the list
```

Comment: its a good idea to do so but i might want to also consider the first element itself.